# Post-hoc testing of an n-way type III ANOVA with interactions in R

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc

I am trying to do a post-hoc test for my data in R, but I can not find any references anywhere on how to do this in R in a way that is appropriate for my data.

My ANOVA was done as so:

```
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly")) ##for TypeIII analysis
aov1 <- aov(Respone~(Factor1+Factor2+Factor3+Factor4)^3)
drop1(aov1,.~.,test="F")
```

I believe that the appropriate test would be to do a Tukey-Kramer on the model, as my data is unbalanced. I have 4 factors, with a differing number of levels. And I have significant 3-way interactions that I would like to compare for significant differences in a 95% confidence interval.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally speaking, pairwise comparisons are not recommended following an interaction.

Comment: Why is that? 

I have graphed all of data, including the three-way interactions. And, for the most part, other than a few cases it is very easy to draw conclusions. But, for the more confusing interactions, I guess I was hoping I could just get p-value to tell me when and where to ignore particular parts of the graphs

Comment: A three-way interaction means that the two-way interactions differ as a function of a third variable. Have you graphed the two-ways separately? If the interaction has 1 df then no follow-up is necessary although sometimes it is informative to test simple two-way interactions. If there is more than 1 df then the sum of squares can be divided up into components. There is not much about an interaction that is relevant to pairwise comparisons or vice versa so it's hard to explain "why not."